# C++ 11 enum class questions?

Tags: c++, enums

I have a question about the difference's between an enum class or strongly typed enum and just a regular enum.

Say I have a enum we'll call it A for this question so

```
enum A {ZERO, ONE, TWO, THREE};
```

I understand that in practice the items inside this enum are considered to be type or class A but can be easily casted to an int or char variable because at the end of the day all enum data is assigned and treated as an int to the compiler.

However in C++ 11 we run into the enum class or strongly typed enum

```
enum class B{ZERO, ONE, TWO, THREE};
```

My question what is the major difference between type A and B? If I say wanted to pull the text not the int out of the enum i could cast it to an char variable. Is that still possible with enum class?? is an enum class still considered an int by the compiler?? I'm sorry if this is a stupid question I'm trying to tech myself to program and I just got to the topic of enums and I'm confused.

Comment: For future reference, your question title should be descriptive of the question you're asking or the problem you're having. Simply repeating tag information is useless. Your title should be clear enough to be useful to a future reader seeing it in a list of search results. If you can't make it specific enough to satisfy that requirement, it's not appropriate to ask here. And this is a **Question** and Answer site. Note that **Question** is singular, not plural. If you have more than one question, create separate posts to ask them.

Comment: Ok I will thanks :)